Is there a simple analytical solution to this two-variable ODE? (using Sympy)
I have a relatively simple but non-linear set of differential equations in two variables:

dx[1]/dt = (u[1] - u[3])  /  A
dx[2]/dt = u[1] * u[2] - u[3] * x[2]  /  (x[1] * A)

I thought this might have an analytical solution so I tried solving it in Sympy following the example posted here.
from sympy import symbols, Function, Eq, dsolve

x1, x2 = symbols('x1, x2', cls=Function)
t, u1, u2, u3, A, x1_init, x2_init = symbols('t, u1, u2, u3, A, x1_init, x2_init')

ode_system = [
    Eq(x1(t).diff(t), (u1 - u3)  /  A), 
    Eq(x2(t).diff(t), u1 * u2 - u3 * x2(t)  /  (x1(t) * A))
]
ics = {x1(0): x1_init, x2(0): x2_init}

sol = dsolve(ode_system, [x1(t), x2(t)], ics=ics)

Sympy does in fact find a solution. The solution for x1(t) is as expected, but the integral for x2(t) is pretty complicated and includes a Piecewise function:
In [2]: sol[0]
Out[2]: Eq(x1(t), x1_init + t*(u1 - u3)/A)

In [3]: sol[1]
Out[3]: Eq(x2(t), u1*u2*Piecewise((exp(u1*log(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3)/(u1 - u3))/u1, Ne(u1, 0)), (log(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3)/(u1 - u3), True))*exp(-u3*log(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3)/(u1 - u3)) - (u1*u2*Piecewise((exp(u1*log(A*C1)/(u1 - u3))/u1, Ne(u1, 0)), (log(A*C1)/(u1 - u3), True)) - x2_init*(A*x1_init)**(u3/(u1 - u3)))*exp(-u3*log(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3)/(u1 - u3)))

I'm having trouble deciphering this...
Is there an obvious simplification to this solution that might work under certain conditions I'm interested in or is it really this complex piecewise function?

Part of the complexity is just comes from whether u1 = u3. If they're equal, x1 is constant and the x2 ODE is an analytically solvable equation.

Similarly, if u1 or u2 equals zero, that makes the second equation easily separable and able to be integrated.

Basically, the reason you're getting these complex piecewise functions is that the nature of the ODE is completely different depending on the above conditions and results in different solutions. Sympy is trying to express this in a clunky way.

Thanks, this makes more sense now. Unfortunately, in general u1 != u3 and u1 > 0, u2 > 0.  Does that mean there is no analytical solution in this case?

Nothing immediately obvious. At this point, the question is better suited for the Math Stack Exchange.

The first equation is trivial to solve, except when A=0 obviously. The second equation can be solved by the usual integrating-factor approach, but that integrating factor depends on the sign of u1-u3. If you had definite values for u1, u2, u3 and A, instead of a whole range of possibilities, it would make it easier to answer your question.

I can give the following conditions which hold in my application: A > 0, u1 >= 0, u2 >= 0, u3 >= 0. However, either u1 < u3 or u1 >= u3.  Strangely, if I put in the first 4 conditions I get a single, simple solution.  So perhaps it doesn't matter if u1 < u3 or u1 >= u3.  See my answer below.

Actually, I found I can avoid the piecewise solution by specifying some assumptions:
A = Symbol('A', positive=True, nonzero=True)
t, x1_init, x2_init = symbols('t, x1_init, x2_init')
u1, u2, u3 = symbols('u1, u2, u3', positive=True)

Then, the solution to the second integral is:
In [52]: sol[1]
Out[52]: Eq(x2(t), u2*(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3) + (A**(u3/(u1 - u3))*x1_init**(u3/(u1 - u3))*x2_init - u2*exp(u1*log(A*C1)/(u1 - u3)))*exp(-u3*log(A*x1_init + t*u1 - t*u3)/(u1 - u3)))

Not sure this can be further simplified.
But it is not a general solution. It causes division-by-zero when u1 == u3.
Update
I solved for the case u1 == u3 separately:
ode_system2 = [
    Eq(x1(t).diff(t), 0), 
    Eq(x2(t).diff(t), u1 * (u2 - x2(t))  /  (x1(t) * A))
]
ics = {x1(0): x1_init, x2(0): x2_init}
sol2 = dsolve(ode_system2, [x1(t), x2(t)], ics=ics)

This gives
In [6]: sol2[1]
Out[6]: Eq(x2(t), u2 - (u2 - x2_init)*exp(-t*u1/(A*x1_init)))

To implement the two possible solutions I used an if statement. After simplifying the equations a little, and after determining that the arbitrary constant C1 should be equal to x1_init, I made the following function to return the solution to the integral from time 0 to t:
def ivp_solution(t, x1_init, x2_init, u1, u2, u3, A):
    u1mu3 = u1 - u3
    if u1mu3 == 0:
        return [
            x1_init,
            u2 - (u2 - x2_init) * np.exp(-t * u1 / (A * x1_init))
        ]
    Ax1initptu1mu3 = A * x1_init + t * u1mu3
    return [
        Ax1initptu1mu3 / A,
        u2 * Ax1initptu1mu3
        + (
            (A * x1_init) ** (u3 / u1mu3) * x2_init 
            - u2 * np.exp(u1 * np.log(A * x1_init) / u1mu3)
        ) * np.exp(-u3 * np.log(Ax1initptu1mu3) / u1mu3)
    ]

